# Real-time searching of GridView control

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the past I've used jQuery/Ajax to capture the key press of an end user, and build up a WHERE clause to filter data on a Web form.

I'm now taking advantage of the strongly type facilitates in ASP.NET 4.5. I was wondering if anyone has a way of performing real-time filtering/searching on a Gridview.

Basically, I have three grids, all showing different information. I want the end-user to key in or select from a drop down list (generic searching) and all girds reflect those changes.

I'm not adverse to resorting back to the old method, just didn't; know if there was anything new I could use?

Comment: you can use jquery data table ... it is so easy to use
https://datatables.net/download/

Comment: Pouya, this is what I have already, just want to know if i can use something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ukW2C/3/). I hope this help you.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input id="searchInput" value="Type To Filter">
    <br/>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="fbody">
            <tr>
                <td>cat</td>
                <td>one</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>dog</td>
                <td>two</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>cat</td>
                <td>three</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>moose</td>
                <td>four</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>mouse</td>
                <td>five</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>dog</td>
                <td>six</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And here is the JavaScript code:

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function () {

    // Split the current value of searchInput
    var data = this.value.split(" ");

    // Create a jQuery object of the rows
    var jo = $("#fbody").find("tr");
    if (this.value == "") {
        jo.show();
        return;
    }

    // Hide all the rows
    jo.hide();

    // Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
    jo.filter(function (i, v) {
        var $t = $(this);
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    })
    // Show the rows that match.
    .show();
}).focus(function () {
    this.value = "";
    $(this).css({
        "color": "black"
    });
    $(this).unbind('focus');
}).css({
    "color": "#C0C0C0"
});
```

[Enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/ukW2C/3/)

Comment: thanks. I shall give that a try. will respond back later today. cheers.

Comment: by the way i've included jsfiddle link

Comment: Yes, it appears to work, just need to roll it into my solution, if it behaves the same there as it does here, then were all good. many thanks.

Comment: just need to figure out how to assign the tbody and id. sounds easy right, well, asp.net grid view doesn't render true html table..

Comment: what about a gridview with paging enabled? above is just working with current gridview page.

Comment: with paging you should use server side search